# Animate slideshow horizontally on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Div with `id="content"` need to change content. I have two `DIV`s, somewhere generated with `id=1` and `id=2`, and I want to div `id="content"` show one,
 but when I **click on some button to change content on another DIV**,  but with smooth horizontal animation, like on image galleries scroll left and right. How to do that with jQuery?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="content">
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

CSS-only example [based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34696029/383904):
It uses **CSS3** `flex` for the template and `transition` for the nice slideshow effect:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}
body{
  font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
  flex: 1;
}
nav ul li a{
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:24px;
  background:#0bf;
  color:#fff;
}
#pages{
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  transition: 1s;
}
#pages section{
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0 32px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.bg1{background:#0af;}
.bg2{background:#f0a;}
.bg3{background:#0fa;}

#home:target ~ #pages{
  transform: translateX(-0%);
}
#about:target ~ #pages{
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
#contact:target ~ #pages{
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" class="bg1">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about" class="bg2">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact" class="bg3">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- dummy anchor targets -->
<i class="target" id="home"></i>
<i class="target" id="about"></i>
<i class="target" id="contact"></i>

<div id="pages">
  <section class="bg1">
    <h1>WELCOME</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure repellendus impedit, fugiat nostrum totam possimus perferendis aut explicabo, perspiciatis veritatis dolorem recusandae ut ratione similique magnam ex tenetur qui doloribus.</p>
  </section>  
  <section class="bg2">
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus praesentium ipsum esse autem quisquam earum accusantium cumque, ipsa ratione saepe sunt voluptatibus fuga perspiciatis reiciendis qui impedit nam itaque incidunt.</p>
  </section>  
  <section class="bg3">
    <h1>CONTACT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum perspiciatis, quae tempore voluptas modi dignissimos asperiores quibusdam adipisci eligendi facilis eos eius corrupti, numquam nulla dolorum, impedit rem fugit rerum?</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

P.S: don't forget to add the needed legacy *-vendor- prefixes* to needed CSS3 properties

Answer (score 1):

It's a multiple step process :

1/Listen for the click event on the button one need to click to switch the content

2/On click you can use the animate function to slide the content you wish to replace out of the container div. Something like

```
$('#id1').animate({'margin-left':'-=500px'},500)
```

should work. The second "500" is the speed of the animation.

3/ Then you need to use the same function to slide the content you wish to show in.

4/ Of course you'd need the correct css style. Something like :

```
#content{
   width:100px //width of your div
   height : 100px // height of your div
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would play a bit and view sources to learn how to do it manually. You can start by inspecting this one: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

If not it has the complete source for download and docs on how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the content of a div is to make available both the sub-div inside it.

Initially make one `display:none;` and on basis of some condition make it as `display:block;`

It works perfectly on Chrome, FF and IE.