# Pure CSS 3 image slider - without JavaScript or radio inputs

Tags: html, css

Is there a way one can create an image slider using just CSS 3 and HTML,
but ***without*** using any of the HTML `input` (radio) elements and no JavaScript?

I had massive search sessions and found stuff that was close and [worked well](http://joshnh.com/weblog/making-a-pure-css-featured-image-slider/), but it was using the HTML radio input.

Comment: You should always remember that CSS layer in web development has nothing to do with behavior / structure and content. CSS is the style layer, so it is about style. You cannot slide through images with merely styles.

Comment: What lead you to the info that for a gallery slider you need input elements?? Have you done any research at all? Any code to share? What and why it did  not worked for you?

Comment: You'd have to use link fragments (e.g. /#image1) to navigate between images on the same page, and contain them all in some fixed container div. This will make the page jump to the top of the fixed div each time though. This is what we did 15 years ago! There are far more elegant solutions today. Why such strict requirements?

Comment: @Cyval that just isn't true anymore.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan what lead me to think that an input had to be used was that everything I came across made use of input elements. It is intended for eBay, and on there you can't use JavaScript nor Input elements in your listing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Pure CSS carousel

*(...Since you're not allowed to use `input radio` elements to maintain the active state...)*
there's another way to make a **sliding gallery** in pure **CSS(3)** using the **`:target` pseudo**.

- `:target` become those `id="foo"` elements who are referenced by a clicked anchor with URI Fragment (Hash) `href="#foo"`
- In CSS, using `:target` pseudo you can than reference down-the-tree to other sibling elements using `~` (*General sibling selectors*), and than you can further access their child elements (slides, buttons etc) as usual.
- *Tip:* If you don't like the "feature" of the gallery **messing with your URL fragments** (*Browser Back button triggering a gallery slide instead of navigating the history!*), you can always **sandbox it** - calling your gallery file **into an `<iframe>`**.

```css
html, body{height:100%;}
body{font:15px/1 sans-serif; margin:0;}

/*
RESPONSIVE CSS3 SLIDE CAROUSEL GALLERY
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34696029/383904
*/

.CSSgal{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:   100%; /* Or set a fixed height */
}

/* SLIDER */
.CSSgal .slider{
  height:      100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size:   0;
  transition:  0.8s;
}

/* SLIDES */
.CSSgal .slider > *{
  font-size:       1rem;
  display:         inline-block;
  vertical-align:  top;
  height:          100%;
  width:           100%;
  background:      none 50% no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* PREV/NEXT, CONTAINERS & ANCHORS */
.CSSgal .prevNext{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:  1;
  top:      50%;
  width:    100%;
  height:   0;
}
.CSSgal .prevNext > div+div{
  visibility: hidden; /* Hide all but first P/N container */
} 
.CSSgal .prevNext a{
  background:  #fff;
  position:    absolute;
  width:       40px;
  height:      40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align:  center;
  opacity:     0.7;
  text-decoration:   none;
  -webkit-transform: translateY( -50% );
          transform: translateY( -50% );
}
.CSSgal .prevNext a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.CSSgal .prevNext a+a{
  right: 0px;
}

/* NAVIGATION */
.CSSgal .bullets{
  position:   absolute;
  z-index:    2;
  bottom:     0;
  padding:    10px 0;
  width:      100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.CSSgal .bullets > a{
  display:         inline-block;
  width:           20px;
  height:          20px;
  line-height:     20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:      center;
  border-radius:   50%;
  background:      rgba(255,255,255,1);
}
.CSSgal .bullets > a+a{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); /* Dim all but first */
}
.CSSgal .bullets > a:hover{
  background: rgba(0,255,255,0.9);
}

/* ACTIVE NAVIGATION ANCHOR */
.CSSgal >s:target ~ .bullets >* { background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); }
#s1:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(1){ background: rgba(255,255,255,  1); }
#s2:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(2){ background: rgba(255,255,255,  1); }
#s3:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(3){ background: rgba(255,255,255,  1); }
#s4:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(4){ background: rgba(255,255,255,  1); }

/* PREV/NEXT CONTAINERS VISIBILITY */
.CSSgal >s:target ~ .prevNext >* { visibility:  hidden; }
#s1:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(1){ visibility: visible; }
#s2:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(2){ visibility: visible; }
#s3:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(3){ visibility: visible; }
#s4:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(4){ visibility: visible; }

/* SLIDER ANIMATION POSITIONS */
#s1:target ~ .slider{ transform: translateX(   0%); -webkit-transform: translateX(   0%); }
#s2:target ~ .slider{ transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
#s3:target ~ .slider{ transform: translateX(-200%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%); }
#s4:target ~ .slider{ transform: translateX(-300%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%); }
```

```html
<div class="CSSgal">

  <!-- Don't wrap targets in parent -->
  <s id="s1"></s> 
  <s id="s2"></s>
  <s id="s3"></s>
  <s id="s4"></s>

  <div class="slider">
    <div style="background:#5fc;">Slide 1</div>
    <div style="background-image:url('//i.imgur.com/squw4Fw.jpg');"></div>
    <div style="background:#fc5;">Slide 3</div>
    <div style="background:#f5c;">Slide 4</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="prevNext">
    <div><a href="#s4">4</a><a href="#s2">2</a></div>
    <div><a href="#s1">1</a><a href="#s3">3</a></div>
    <div><a href="#s2">2</a><a href="#s4">4</a></div>
    <div><a href="#s3">3</a><a href="#s1">1</a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bullets">
    <a href="#s1">1</a>
    <a href="#s2">2</a>
    <a href="#s3">3</a>
    <a href="#s4">4</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Ciwan you're welcome. Note that the above will not work in older browsers 1. cause the use of CSS3 transition, 2. cause of the CSS `~` selector. Also don't forget to add all the necessary `-vendor-` prefixes like for `-webkit-transition` etc...

Comment: Is there a way to make this works with arrows rather than active bullets? Two arrows for left and right?

Comment: @Ciwan that complicates the HTML (and CSS) a lot but it's doable. Simply, for every slide you need a pair of PREV/NEXT buttons (anchors) with the proper URI Fragment (Hash) `href="#sN"` which will point to the prev/next slide accordingly.

Comment: How to add more than 4 slides?  Figured it out. You have to change the CSS too. Although good, this is not a very scalable solution. Too many changes needed to add extra slides.

Comment: @Shardul well, not if you create a tool (with JavaScript or other) to help in the making. But now, it's not dynamic. If you need something dynamic than you don't need a static HTML/CSS-only solution at all. You can use a JS slider.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan how can I use only three slides and have it always go forward, so after 3 the first one slides in from the righ to left?

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth I don't think CSS is the right tool to create an ***infinite slideshow***. You might want to take a look at i.e: [this infinite slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72992704/383904) that uses JavaScript - if that is what you were looking for

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks, but I don't need autoplay, and no bullets. How could I remove both?

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth Here's an example with the removed JS and CSS related parts: https://jsfiddle.net/1z4wd7mc/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan AWESOME!! Thank you! Two litle issues though: when first opening the page, the last image is quickly seen ad the first slides in. How to avoid that and have the first one be visible when opening the page? And one little thing? Is it possible to have a small padding between the images like here: https://swiffyslider.com/configuration/?slider-nav-style=slider-nav-arrow

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth I cannot replicate the images loading issue (and have not the time right now to explore). For the spacing between slides, add: `margin-right: 20px;` to the `.carousel-slide {`, and in JS use instead: ``elCarouselSlider.style.transform = `translateX(calc(${(-c - 1) * 100}% - ${20 * (c + 1)}px))`;``  (notice the `20`) https://jsfiddle.net/rshnw67j/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan sorry for bugging you again, I am just trying to learn...is it possible in your last fiddle to have multiple slides visible at one time? For a product carousel?

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth A bunch of code should be changed both in CSS I believe and specially in the part in JavaScript where we use `cloneNode`. One important aspect is also the logic about keeping track of the current index. With some simple math in place, and depending on if the slider should advance two-by-two or move one by one, and keeping in mind responsiveness and what should happen in case of a mobile device? Should in that case switch to sliding one full width and clone one slide only? Too many questions. Have you tried to play around? Any fiddle to share of a current progress?

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth one ultra simple workaround would be to simply treat one slide as a dummy container for two children (images or DIVs or whatever). [[a1][a2]] [[b1][b2]]... the only caveat would be to always try to have an even number of child elements (meaning, try not to leave the last slide with only half content, half empty ;) - if that matters nitpickingly)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank yu. Well, I simply tried changing the css to 33.333%(in order to have three), b ut it does  not work well, there is a problem after the last slide with white spaace and the first slide not loading immediately... https://jsfiddle.net/drenina/dwcjn93z/1/  And yes, it should be only one image below 768px.

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth using the demo link you provided, one step forward would be perhaps using 33.333% instead of 100% like: `translateX(calc(${(-c - 1) * 33.333}% - ${20*(c + 1)}px))` - and then move from that point onward. One next step would be to clone two first elements (append the first two) and also prepend the last two elements clones. That's basically it. Oh, yes, and use `-2` instead of `-1` like `translateX(calc(${(-c - 2) * 33.333}% - ${20*(c + 1)}px))` (since we prepended TWO slides instead of one).

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/yLg95p0h/ - obviously that's all nasty and hardcoded. Would be better if you collected some data attributes that could configure each slider and create a better reusable logic like `data-visible-slides="3"` etc, you got the idea. But that's a good start.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that's great thank you! There is still the issue of not loading the next image immediately, oddly it is only between the second and third slider image! And the 20px padding is on the left of the first image as well, trying to figure out how to have the first image start at the container, and have the last/third end at the container as well...

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/21fx6ge7/ this example uses CSS vars. And notice how you can set `style="--visible-slides: 3;"` and it magically works. Ask if something is not clear.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thank you!!! I added a negative margin of .5rem to the carousel div in order to adjust for the .5 padding from the slides, hope that is correct? Also, do you do custom work as well(paid of course)? In case we need help in the future :)

Comment: @MartinaSchuberth  Sure, I could help you in the future if you get stuck. I have some info in my profile.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan this works so well, thank you again! One question: I tried setting visibl slides to 3.5 in order to have a reveal effect, and it works, but after some images there is white space, meaning the js isn' t loading the next images fast enough. I guess having the reveal effect would need more work?