# Use more pure CSS slideshow in OpenCart 3

Tags: css, opencart

I am trying to make more than a slide show in tabbed slideshow in OpenCart 3 homepage.

I make it but it works only with usual HTML. When I put it in OpenCart 3 the slide becomes damaged.

[my opencart](http://eemaar.info/blackshopp/)

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
*{box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }

/*
PURE RESPONSIVE CSS3 SLIDESHOW GALLERY by Roko C. buljan
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34696029/383904
*/

.CSSgal2 {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%; /* Or set a fixed height */
}

/* slider2 */

.CSSgal2 .slider2 {
 height: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: 0.8s;
}

/* SLIDES */

.CSSgal2 .slider2 > * {
 font-size: 1rem;
 display: inline-block;
 white-space: normal;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background: none 50% no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}

/* PREV/NEXT, CONTAINERS & ANCHORS */

.CSSgal2 .prevNext {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 50%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 0;
}

.CSSgal2 .prevNext > div+div {
 visibility: hidden; /* Hide all but first P/N container */
}

.CSSgal2 .prevNext a {
 background: #fff;
 position: absolute;
 width:       60px;
 height:      60px;
 line-height: 60px; /* If you want to place numbers */
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0.7;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
     transition: 0.3s;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
 left: 0;
}
.CSSgal2 .prevNext a:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.CSSgal2 .prevNext a+a {
 left: auto;
 right: 0;
}

/* NAVIGATION */

.CSSgal2 .bullets {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
.CSSgal2 .bullets > a {
 display: inline-block;
 width:       30px;
 height:      30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
     transition: 0.3s;
}
.CSSgal2 .bullets > a+a {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); /* Dim all but first */
}
.CSSgal2 .bullets > a:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) !important;
}

/* NAVIGATION BUTTONS */
/* ALL: */
.CSSgal2 >s:target ~ .bullets >* {      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);}
/* ACTIVE */
#s1:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(1) {background: rgba(255, 255, 255,   1);}
#s2:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(2) {background: rgba(255, 255, 255,   1);}
#s3:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(3) {background: rgba(255, 255, 255,   1);}
#s4:target ~ .bullets >*:nth-child(4) {background: rgba(255, 255, 255,   1);}
/* More slides? Add here more rules */

/* PREV/NEXT CONTAINERS VISIBILITY */
/* ALL: */
.CSSgal2 >s:target ~ .prevNext >* {      visibility: hidden;}
/* ACTIVE: */
#s1:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(1) {visibility: visible;}
#s2:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(2) {visibility: visible;}
#s3:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(3) {visibility: visible;}
#s4:target ~ .prevNext >*:nth-child(4) {visibility: visible;}
/* More slides? Add here more rules */

/* slider2 ANIMATION POSITIONS */

#s1:target ~ .slider2 {transform: translateX(   0%); -webkit-transform: translateX(   0%);}
#s2:target ~ .slider2 {transform: translateX(-100%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);}
#s3:target ~ .slider2 {transform: translateX(-200%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);}
#s4:target ~ .slider2 {transform: translateX(-300%); -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);}
/* More slides? Add here more rules */


/* YOU'RE THE DESIGNER! 
   ____________________
   All above was mainly to get it working :)
   CSSgal2 CUSTOM STYLES / OVERRIDES HERE: */

.CSSgal2{
 color: #fff; 
 text-align: center;
}
.CSSgal2 .slider2 h2 {
 margin-top: 40vh;
 font-weight: 200;
 letter-spacing: -0.06em;
 word-spacing: 0.2em;
 font-size: 3em;
}
.CSSgal2 a {
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 0 3px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 text-decoration: none;
}
/* Style the tab */
.tab {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 22px 16px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current "tab button" class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 12px;
    width: 80%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onClick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
<div class="CSSgal2">

  <!-- Don't wrap targets in parent -->
  <s id="s1"></s> 
  <s id="s2"></s>
  <s id="s3"></s>
  <s id="s4"></s>

  <div class="slider2">
    <div style="background:#5b8;">
   <h2>PURE <b>CSS</b> SLIDESHOW</h2>
   <p>Responsive Slideshow Gallery created using CSS only<br>by Roko</p>
  </div>
    <div style="background:#85b;">
   <h2>Slide 2</h2>
  </div>
    <div style="background:#e95;">
   <h2>Slide 3</h2>
  </div>
    <div style="background:#e59;">
   <h2>Slide 4</h2>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="prevNext">
    <div><a href="#s4"></a><a href="#s2"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#s1"></a><a href="#s3"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#s2"></a><a href="#s4"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#s3"></a><a href="#s1"></a></div>
  </div>

  <div class="bullets">
    <a href="#s1">1</a>
    <a href="#s2">2</a>
    <a href="#s3">3</a>
    <a href="#s4">4</a>
  </div>

</div>

</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>test</h3>
  <p>test</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>test</h3>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i've removed the slide from the web wait'n for any one answer

Comment: What does "damaged" mean? Please read [ask], then come back and [edit] your question to make it as clear as possible.