# How do I animate this with only using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to be able to animate this code for a project I am working on. I can change the slides with the buttons but I also want it to stay on a slide for 30s then move to the next and pause on hover. I want the slides to repeat to. I am having a little issue with this. I am new to coding,

## slide 1

your content here

## Slide 2

your content here

### slide 3

Your content here

‹
      ›
      ‹
      ›
      ‹
      ›

•

•

```css
<style>

.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet {
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
.carousel li.carousel-1 {
  animation: cycle 30s linear infinite;
}

.carousel li.carousel-2 {
  animation: cycle2 30s linear infinite;
}

.carousel li.carousel-3 {
  animation: cycle3 30s linear infinite;
}
.carousel:hover li {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes cycle {
  0%   {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* Starts in view */
  30%  {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* In view */
  33%  {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Slides out of view [to bottom] */
  63%  {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves to back [z-index] */
  66%  {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves back to top out of sight */ 
  96%  {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Moves back to front [z-index] */
  100% {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* Return to start */
  }
  @keyframes cycle2 {
  0%   {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves back to top out of sight */
  30%  {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Moves back to front [z-index] */
  33%  {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* Slides into view [from top] */
  63%  {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* In view */
  66%  {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Slides out of view [to bottom] */ 
  96%  {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves to back [z-index] */
  100% {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Return to start */
  }
  
  @keyframes cycle3 {
  0%   {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Slides out of view [to bottom] */
  30%  {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves to back [z-index] */
  33%  {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;}  /* Moves back to top out of sight */
  63%  {top: -325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Moves back to front [z-index] */
  66%  {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* Slides into view [from top] */ 
  96%  {top:    0px; opacity: 1; z-index:  1;}  /* In view */
  100% {top:  325px; opacity: 0; z-index:  1;}  /* Return to start */
  }  

</style>
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>slide 1</h1> 
         <p>your content here</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h1>Slide 2</h1> 
      <p>your content here</p> 
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
         <h2>slide 3</h2> 
        <p>Your content here</p> 
      </div> 
     
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">›</label> 
      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">•</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">•</label> </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

```
        <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">•</label> </li> 

  </ol>
```

Comment: Did u tried key frames? Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989585/css-3-slide-in-from-left-transition) and [this](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/slideshow.en.html) if you would like to try

Comment: To create a carousel with pause on hover, navigation and arrows - **the simplest you could do is use just a bit of JavaScript**. CSS is no meant to ease your job on such tasks. If you really want to have a glimpse on a CSS example (without autoslide) https://codepen.io/rokobuljan/pen/XXzqKQ from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34696029/383904

Comment: I have a different one that has jquery plug-in but the slide dots are messed up. I don't know enough about javascript to fix it.