# Infinite looping div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a div section that has multiple divs in it. There are two buttons and I want the div to loop on each side indefinitely.

```js
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.scroll-layout');
const scrollLeftButton = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
const scrollRightButton = document.getElementById('scroll-right');

scrollLeftButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollContainer.scrollBy({
    left: -200, // Adjust the scroll amount as needed
    behavior: 'smooth' // Enable smooth scrolling
  });
});

scrollRightButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollContainer.scrollBy({
    left: 200, // Adjust the scroll amount as needed
    behavior: 'smooth' // Enable smooth scrolling
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="scroll-layout">
    <div class="scroll-item">1</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">2</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">3</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">4</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">5</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">6</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">7</div>
    <div class="scroll-item">8</div>
  </div>
  <button class="scroll-button left" id="scroll-left"> ◀</button>
  <button class="scroll-button right" id="scroll-right"> ▶</button>
</div>
```

[image]
This is how it looks. I want the 1 box to appear after the 8 and continue to do so.

Comment: You mean a carrousel?

Comment: yeah exactly like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Carousel slideshow with infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72992704/383904)